# Getting core dumped?

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


typedef struct shop {

         string custName;

         string custAdd;

         string custNum;

         string custClothPrice;



struct shop* next;

}

shop;



int main (void)



{
struct shop* head; 



   head = NULL;

struct shop* pointer=NULL; 


printf("**********WELCOME TO AZIZIYAH CREATIONS**********\n\n"); 

char cont = 'y';


printf("Please enter customer details\n");

printf("Please Enter NAME   : ");



  head->custName = GetString();

printf("Please Enter Address: ");

  head->custAdd = GetString();

printf("Please Enter Cell No: ");

  head->custNum = GetString();
printf("Please Enter Price  : ");

  head->custClothPrice = GetString();

return 0;

printf("Would you liked to add more customer(s)?: Y/N:");


  cont = GetChar();

  head->next = pointer;

if (cont == 'Y' || cont == 'y')



 {

    pointer = malloc(sizeof(shop));

    pointer->next = NULL;

    }
while (cont == 'y' || cont == 'Y' )

{

printf("Please enter customer details\n");

printf("Please Enter NAME   : ");

    pointer->custName = GetString();

printf("Please Enter Address: ");

    pointer->custAdd = GetString();

printf("Please Enter Cell No: ");

    pointer->custNum = GetString();

printf("Please Enter Price  : ");

    pointer->custClothPrice = GetString();

printf("Would you liked to add more customer(s)?: Y/N:");

    cont = GetChar();
if (cont == 'Y' || cont == 'y')

{

    pointer->next = malloc(sizeof(shop));
    pointer = pointer ->next;

        }



    }

printf("\n\nDETAILS OF CUSTOMER ARE AS FOLLOWS:-\n");

struct shop* traverse;

    traverse = head;

    if (traverse->next == NULL)

printf("WAS FOUND NULL\n");



while (traverse->next != NULL)

{

printf("%s\n", traverse->custName);

printf("%s\n", traverse->custAdd);

printf("%s\n", traverse->custNum);

printf("%s\n", traverse->custClothPrice);

   traverse = traverse->next;
    }

    printf("**********THANK YOU FOR VISITING**********\n");   

}
```

Had made an application it producing an error of Segmentation fault (core dumped) after First Input
OutPut
**********WELCOME TO AZIZIYAH CREATIONS**********

Please enter customer details
Please Enter NAME   : asd
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

kindly help please

Comment: Please always write down your question, “kindly help please” is not a question. What are we supposed to help you with? What do you want us to do?

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment to `head->custName` causes your crash: You need to allocate memory for `head` before you can write something to where it points to. If you don't do that, your program crashes. You can allocate memory for `head` with `malloc()` like this:

```
head = malloc(sizeof *head);
if (head == NULL) {
    /* error handling code here */
}
```

Remember to insert appropriate error handling code.

Comment: Okay got some but can you please elaborate some more?

Comment: @SayYid What would you like me to elaborate about?